# SSLProxyCACertificateFile fails "incomplete client cert configured for ssl proxy" : Whats wrong?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, openssl

I would like to convert the p12 file at https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition/blob/master/projects/repository/config/alfresco/keystore/browser.p12?raw=true so it can be used in the apache2 `SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile` directive. I converted it using

```
openssl pkcs12 -in browser.p12 -nodes -out alfresco.pem # (password is 'alfresco')
```

ending up

```
AH02252: incomplete client cert configured for SSL proxy (missing or encrypted private key?)
```

when I start apache. As far as I can tell, the key in the pem file should not be encrypted and also match the certificate so it looks like a bug to me.

I am running Apache/2.4.10 (ubuntu 14.10) and open OpenSSL 1.0.1f.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try changing the line in your alfresco.pem from `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`   to `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

Comment: That was one piece of the puzzle. The other part is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872482/error-during-ssl-handshake-with-remote-server

Comment: @FedericoSierra comment is GOLD because I didn't see that anywhere in the docs and apache httpd does not seem to work if you don't define it. Great catch! +10!! I was banging my head against the wall trying to make "SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile" work and this did it. Thank you!!!

Comment: @ezra-s Thanks for the comment. I put a reference of where this problem appears in the answer

Answer (score 3):

You can fix this issue by changing the line in the key file from:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
```

to

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The problem appear with openssl 1.0.x  which changed (comparing to 0.9) its default private key format.

See more:
https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55673